# Lattice Energy of MX2 type

Tags: physical-chemistry, ions, ionic-compounds, lattices

While finding the solution to the question that which among BaO and BaCl2 has hi that is energy I found that it was BaO whose lattice energy is high and there were explaining it just with charges. So I am bit confused that why did they not consider the the fact that there were 2 Cl atoms in BaCl2